# How to group values based on a “connectedness” metric if there be some missing numbers in first column?

Tags: linux, shell

There is a file with three columns. Columns 1 and 2 contain numbers are not from the same set. In fact, some numbers that exist in column 2, may not exist in column1.

Column 3 shows the amount of connectedness between numbers in columns 1 and 2.

I want to partition my numbers in column 1  into groups of consecutive values (i.e., ranges) for which connectedness is greater than or equal to 0.2.  For example, in this small data set:

input:

```
1   2       0.000
1   3       0.213
1   4       0.014
1   5       0.001
1   6       0.555
1   7       0.509
1   8       0.509
3   4       0.995
3   5       0.323
3   6       0.555
3   7       0.225
3   8       0.000
4   5       0.095
4   6       0.058
4   7       0.335
4   8       0.000
5   6       0.995
5   7       0.658
5   8       0.000
6   7       0.431
6   8       0.000
7   8       0.000
```

the output should be like:

output:

```
 G1: 1 3    G2: 4   G3 :5 6 7
```

As you see number 2 is missing in column1. so we not consider 2 in a group. Connectedness between 1 with 3, is greater than 0.2, so 1 and 3 should be placed in first group. In fact, any pair of numbers within a group must have enough connectedness together. Despite high relation between 1/3 and 6 (0.555 > 0.2), 6 should not be placed in the first group, since numbers between 1 and 6 in column 1(4 and 5) had low connectedness with 1. So we must not jump over 4 and 5 and connect numbers in the first group with 6.

Number 4 does not have the high connectedness with 5, so number 4 should be in the second group individually. No matter that 4 has a high connectedness with 7 since the previous numbers (5 and 6) were in low connectedness with 4 and we must not jump over numbers in between and connect 4 with 7.

5 has a high connectedness with 6, 7 and 8. Also, any pair of numbers (like 6/7, 6/8) have high connectedness together. Therefore they should be placed together in the third group. That is why all of these numbers can be placed in one group.

Note that the real data does not begin from number 1 and there are over 100,000 lines. Also, there might be a couple of missing numbers in column1 in which exist in column2. but always the connectedness of missing numbers in column 1 is zero with other numbers.Also, note that column1 may begin with a number biggar than 1.

here is a part of my real data:
input:

```
    49996 49997 0.000
    49996 49998 0.082
    49996 49999 0.953
    49996 50000 0.060
    49996 50001 0.000
    49998 49999 0.288
    49998 50000 0.288
    49998 50001 0.000
    49999 50000 0.265
    49999 50001 0.000
    50000 50001 0.000
```

output should be:

```
  G1:49996   G2: 49998 49999 50000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example doesn't have 8 in the first column, so shouldn't appear in the results based on your specs.  Trying with the second sample

```
$ awk             'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} 
                !($2 in a){next} 
       p!=$1 && !($1 in a){next} 
                    $3<0.2{p=$1; next} 
          p!=$1 && $3>=0.2{g[$1]=(g[$1]?g[$1] FS $2:$2); 
                           delete a[$2]} 
                       END{for(k in g) {print "G"++c,k,g[k]; delete a[k]} 
                           for(k in a) print "G"++c,k}' file2{,}

G1 49998 49999 50000
G2 49996
```

some brave soul can simply this further.

**UPDATE**
To change the order of groups, better to post process them, change the `END` block to this

```
... END{for(k in g) {print k,g[k]; delete a[k]} 
        for(k in a) print k}' file2{,} | 
sort | 
awk '{print "G"NR":",$0}'

G1: 49996
G2: 49998 49999 50000
```

**UPDATE 2**  Here is a somewhat simplified version

```
$ awk '                         NR == FNR {a[$1]; next}
      !( $2 in a && (p == $1 || $1 in a)) {next}    
                                 $3 < 0.2 {p=$1; next}    
                                  p != $1 {g[$1]=g[$1]?g[$1] FS $2:$2; delete a[$2]}    
                                      END {for (k in g) {print k, g[k]; delete a[k]}
                                           for (k in a) print k}' file{,} |
 sort |
 awk '{print "G"NR":",$0}'
```

Comment: your second update does not work at al. but you first update works but the problem with it is that the numbers inside groups do not come in the right odrer ( from small numbers to big numbers). this is while in my file, numbers begins from small numbers  and they end with big ones. so i should expect an order of numbers across groups. But I see this :G1: 1
G2: 100
G3: 1001
G4: 1002
G5: 1003 1004 1005
G6: 1006 1007
G7: 1008
G8: 1009
G9: 101
G10: 1010

Comment: why 101 should be in a gruop after 1001, 1002 and ect? but 101 should be grouped before any number bigger that 101.

Comment: to fix that change `sort` to `sort -n`.

Comment: ok thanks. and if I want to run 100 files at a same time(file1 file2 .. file100) and have 100 outputs(out1 ...out100), then how should I change the program? I tried to make loop but ... I can not by this  program :(

Comment: you should write a for loop and for each file `f` call the script (you should write `"$f"{,}` instead of file{,} and output to some file name derived from `f`.

Comment: ok. I did this change and I saved your script in test.sh . and I made a loop like this: for((i=1;i<101;i++));do test.sh file$i > out$i; done. but it doesnot run. it does not give any error. but it does not run either. do you know where did i do wrong?

Comment: Read my previous comment please.

Comment: can you explain a little more clear please? what I did is what I understood from your previous comment.

Comment: It's scanning the file twice. The way I wrote it requires that you provide the same file twice `file file` or shorthand `file{,}` I'm guessing that's what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had to start from scratch instead of editing my reply to your [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/301652/13792), as I needed to prepreocess the input file first to get a list of numbers to consider (i.e. the numbers from the first column).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $THRESHOLD = 0.2;

my @considered;
open my $IN, '<', shift or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
    my ($first) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    push @considered, $first unless @considered && $first == $considered[-1];
}

seek $IN, 0, 0;
my $considered_idx = 0;
my @groups = ([ $considered[$considered_idx] ]);
while (<$IN>) {
    my ($n1, $n2, $connectedness) = split;
    next if $n1 == $considered[$considered_idx]
         && $n2 < $considered[ 1 + $considered_idx ];

    next if $n2 > $considered[-1];

    if ($n1 == $considered[$considered_idx]) {
        if ($connectedness > $THRESHOLD) {
            push @{ $groups[-1] }, $n2;

        } else {
            ++$considered_idx until $considered_idx > $#considered
                                 || $considered[$considered_idx] >= $n2;
            push @groups, [ $considered[$considered_idx] ];
        }
    }
}

for my $i (0 .. $#groups) {
    print "$i\t@{ $groups[$i] }\n";
}
```

Comment: why this program does not work on second example which is a part of my real data? it only works on first example. when I run it on secound one, i get theses too many errors: Use of uninitialized value $first in numeric eq (==) at ./haploblock.perl line 11, <$IN> line 12.
Use of uninitialized value $considered[-1] in numeric gt (>) at ./haploblock.perl line 22, <$IN> line 14.
Use of uninitialized value $considered[-1] in numeric gt (>) at

Comment: Use of uninitialized value $considered[-1] in numeric gt (>) at ./haploblock.perl line 22, <$IN> line 22.
Use of uninitialized value $considered[-1] in numeric gt (>) at ./haploblock.perl line 22, <$IN> line 23.
Use of uninitialized value $n1 in numeric eq (==) at ./haploblock.perl line 19, <$IN> line 24.
Use of uninitialized value $considered[-1] in numeric gt (>) at ./haploblock.perl line 22, <$IN> line 24.
Use of uninitialized value $n2 in numeric gt (>) at ./haploblock.perl lin

Comment: i can not paste all the error I see, since they are too many. do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Are there any empty lines in the input? Adding `next if /^\s*$/` should skip them.